# my codeigniter v.3 website not working on liver server which has fine on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i had recently switched ci v.3 
and i had faced problems
my live server redirect to me 404 error page when i hit my url 
it was perfectly fine on local host but it's not working on server.
my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]




# 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----

IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: turn on the error_reporting on live server and than check the error message because mostly error_reporting is not enabled on live server if you are using Development & Production folders for configurations.

Comment: I think you are jumping to conclusions if you think that "Not working" implies a problem in htaccess.

Comment: Imran i dont get it would u make it easier for me

Comment: Goleztrol i have no idea what is wrong would u kindly tell me what should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rename the file to ucfirst for folder controller and model.

Please refer http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your controller file name:
e.g: about.php to About.php